# Allowed host for Django with uWSGI not connecting using IPV6?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

Allowed host for Django with uWSGI not  connecting?  Allowed hosts are

```
[::]:8080
```

and

```
[domain_name::]:8080
```

uWSGI in terminal is:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/mysite --chdir /home/user/mysite -w mysite.wsgi
```

so trying

```
wwww.domain_name.com:8080
```

is not connecting.

But with the development server it is connecting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is a typo but you have four w's in your domain. However, this is very likely a question typo.

For production domains - you shouldn't need to specify the port number. So, in your `settings.py` I would set:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.domain_name.com']
```

However, if this still doesn't work - perhaps try:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

The asterisk or star is a wild card on domain, and allows any connections that request the uWSGI process.

The next possible reason for this issue is that your port 8080 is not open on the production server that you're using and whether this port accepts IPv6. The next step could also be whether the browser you're using accepts IPv6 connections and if you need to configure both an A and AAAA name records for your chosen domain.

If the wildcard still doesn't work - scream and I will likely need more errors to be able to debug this issue for you.